# difficulties in understanding GroupLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

[image]

I wanted to do something that looks like the one which frame is in BLUE(right side), so i started out with a simple one which has 3 panels(on the top left)

I couldn't seems to figure out how to use `GroupLayout` and the following is my code for it. It turns out to be the one on the bottom left. Anyone can tell me where is wrong with my understanding on `GroupLayout` ? Thanks.

```
layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
        .addComponent(yellow)
        .addComponent(green)
        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup())
            .addComponent(pink)

    );
layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup())
            .addComponent(yellow)
            .addComponent(green)
        .addComponent(pink) 
    );
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) +1 for the diagrams.

Comment: 1) GroupLayout isn't designated for hand_coding (even is possible), 2) most easiest is to use NestedLayout, to split important areas to the separate JPanels layed by different LayoutManager (or the same) 3)otherwise have look at GridBagLayout or custom MigLayout

Comment: So in what situation should I use GroupLayout?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the horizontal layout you have an upper part (yellow/green) and a lower part (pink) in **parallel**. The upper part displays a **sequence** of yellow and green:

```
layout.setHorizontalGroup(
    layout.createParallelGroup()                    // upper and lower part show parallel layout
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()    // <- upper part
            .addComponent(yellow)
            .addComponent(green)
        ).addComponent(pink)                        // <- lower part
);
```

On the other hand the vertical layout is a **sequence** of upper part (yellow and green in **parallel**, i.e. side by side) and the lower part (pink).

```
layout.setVerticalGroup(
    layout.createSequentialGroup()                  // upper and lower part sequentially
        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup()      // <- upper part
            .addComponent(yellow)
            .addComponent(green)
        ).addComponent(pink)                        // <- lower part
);
```